# Excel Median for multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically in excel I want a table, like the one given below on the right (the scale of my data is a lot bigger than the example given),that has the median for each subject, for each condition (e.g. TADA, TADP, TPDA, TPDP). Ideally, I would use a pivot table, however, excel does not do 'median' in a pivot table. I was wondering if there was a formula I could to save me having to go through manually and working out the median, i've tried a few (along to lines of "median(if etc.." but my coding knowledge in excel is very poor. Is there a short way to do this?

```
 Data                               Table
Subject    RT  condition            Subject    TADA   TADP  TPDA  TPDP
  1        23  TADA                    1
  1        54  TPDA                    2
  1        65  TADA                    3
  1        67  TPDP
  1        76  TADA
  2        72  TPDA
  2        87  TADA
  2        12  TPDP
  2        45  TADP
  2        32  TPDP
  2        87  TADA
  3        98  TPDA
  3        12  TADA
  3        53  TPDA
  3        78  TADP
  3        98  TPDP
```

Comment: May not be ideal, but take a look at this: http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/12317/How-to-Create-the-Elusive-Pivot-Table-With-Medians-Excel-Tip.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Assuming data in A2:C100 and then your results table with headers in F1 across and row labels in E2 down you can use an array formula like this in F2

`=MEDIAN(IF($A$2:$A$100=$E2,IF($C$2:$C$100=F$1,$B$2:$B$100)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied across and down

extend data ranges as required

Comment: Thank you! That has been a great help. The only thing is that it is not copying down or across correctly, is there a way to make it do that? Thank again

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - simplest way is to drag down using the "fill-handle". Put formula in F2 and confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Now select F2 and put cursor on botton right of cell until you see a black "+". That's the "fill-handle" - press left mouse button and hold while you drag down. Release mouse after. Now you can drag that whole column across in the same way

Comment: When I try this on a modest data set, it results in the median of the whole data set, not just the median of the subset that satisfies the condition.