# Excel: Find the median of a subset of data

Tags: excel

Suppose I have a data set in Excel like

```
1, 10
2, 15
3, 20
4, 25
```

and let's say the left column starts at A1, the right column starts at B1.  And say I want to get the median of the numbers in column B which correspond to values in A less than 3, which should return 12.5.  I tried the formula as suggested here: [Excel Median for multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026545/excel-median-for-multiple-conditions#19026838)

I entered in another cell, the formula

```
= MEDIAN(IF($A1:$A4<3, $B1:$B4))
```

and I've tried permutations of where to place the dollar sign, but it always outputs the median of the whole B column, 17.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried the formula as suggested here: [Excel Median for multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19026838/1505120)

Not as indicated - it is required to be in the array version:

> **confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

Replace `=` with `=`, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the answer--I know that what I'm trying to do is not exactly the same as what's in that link, but I tried the minimal adaptation to accomplish my goal.  If this doesn't work, then how else might I try to get the median of a subset of data?

Comment: Replace `=` with `=`?   Just to re-type it, or is there an actual change?

Comment: Oh, when I did this it inserted curly braces!  I was unaware that those actually did anything, I thought people just included them in answers to indicate that it was code or something.  Works now, many thanks.