# How to search within different intervals and get Median

Tags: excel

Can anyone help with "easy" formula in following dillemma in Excel?

I have Table 1 ans Table 2.
Table 1 looks something like that:

```
Kolumn A      Kolumn B       Kolumn C 
Min Salary    Max Salary     Tax %
60000         61200          8,3%
61212         62400          8,4%
62412         63600          8,6%
63612         64800          8,7%
64812         66000          9,0%
66012         67200          9,2%
67212         68400          9,4%
68412         69600          9,6%
69612         70800          9,9% 
etc
```

Table 2

```
Kolumn A   Kolumn B
Salary     Percentage

60000
65000
70000
```

into Table B in Kolumn B i would need to get Median % from Kolumn C in table 1 within correct Salary intervals.

Any good suggestions?
Thankful in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Median for multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026545/excel-median-for-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Hi Not quitely. But your advice about MEDIAN formula gave med inspiration. :-) I chose following solution. =MAX(IF(Table1'!$A:$A<0;Table1'!$C:$C)) I.e. Pick up in Table 1 minimum % within interval and then =MIN(IF(Table1'!$B:$B>Table2A2;Table1'!$C:$C)), i.e pick up in Table 2 max % within interval and then calculate median between this min and max %. So thanks for inspiration that pushed my thinking process to right direction.